# Connecting to MongoDB using PDO driver

Tags: php, mongodb, driver

Will I be able to connect to this database using PHP's *php_mongo.dll* driver?

If so, could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/<dbname>/collections/<collection>/?apiKey=<my_api_key>  - this is what I use for rest call back.. but is there a way for connecting to this using php drivers?

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 21):

MongoDB requires its own driver.

In your case, the PHP driver is located here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

The instructions for installing it are on that page. There is also some sample code.

Comment: not working anymore

Answer (score 4):

I think that PDO is only for relational databases. There's no PDO driver for MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

There is list of databases which you can use with the PDO driver: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php. MongoDB is not among them.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the comments below the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP PDO OBDC library, if you install MongoDB BI Connector and MongoDB ODBC Driver for BI Connector.

I haven’t tried it, but I’m about to - keep you posted.

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/bi-connector
https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/odbc-driver/